# Program doesn't use all hardware resources

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on one program that takes information from files and then stores them in MySQL database. This MySQL database is located in another dedicated server which is much more powerful than this server here. Data is being sent over LAN using 1gbps connection.

It is using 8 threads because my server has 8 cores, but somehow it runs so slowly.

- CPU is: Intel Xeon E3-1270 v 3 @ 3.50Ghz
- RAM: 16 GB ECC
- HDD: SATA 3 1TB

My program's CPU usage is only 0-5%
CPU affinity is all 8 cores

So, do you have any ideas what's wrong or how can I increase the speed of my program?

**UPDATE:**

I updated my code and it appears to be faster:

```
Parallel.For(0, this.data_files.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = this.MaxThreads }, i =>
{
        this.ThreadCount++;
        this.ParseFile(this.GetSource());                            
});
```

<s>Here's a code snippet that deploys threads:</s>

```
while (true)
{
    if (this.ThreadCount < this.MaxThreads)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            this.ParseFile(this.GetFile())
        );

        this.ThreadCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }

    this.UpdateConsole();

}
```

GetFile function:

```
private string GetFile()
{
    string file = "";
    string source = "";

        while (true)
        {
            if (this.data_files.Count() != 0)
            {
                file = this.data_files[0];
                this.data_files.RemoveAt(0);

                if (File.Exists(file) == true)
                {
                    source = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    File.Delete(file);
                    break;
                }
            }

    }

    return source;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell where is bottleneck without ParseFile\GetFile methods. But i doubt it's file system bottleneck

Comment: If it were that easy to utilize all resources, some of us wouldn't have jobs. :D:D:D

Comment: Your program is probably I/O-bound. Generally operations such as reading a file from disk are very slow even though they do not use the CPU a lot.

Comment: I updated my post with more information

Comment: Hm, you have `lock` in `GetFiles` that blocks all other threads to read different files. It's not so good for multithreading

Comment: Thanks, I removed a lock, but it's still pretty slow. I really don't see any changes in speed

Comment: I updated my post with a new code

Comment: But now you have a potential race condition.

Comment: Hmm.. any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Consider using a ConcurrentQueue and TryDequeue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> I'm working on one program that takes information from files and then stores them in MySQL database.

Clearly your program is not CPU bound, it's IO bound.  The bottlenecks are going to be based on your hard disk(s) and your network connection.  Odds are even a single thread is going to be able to ensure proper utilization of these resources (in a well designed application).  Adding extra threads generally won't help, it'll just create a bunch of threads that will spend their time waiting on various IO operations.

Comment: I added "Get file" function. Also I updated my post with database information

Comment: @Jason Okay...the point here is that *no matter what you do you won't have a high CPU utilization*.  CPU time is not a scarce resource for your program, you have way more CPU time than you need.  If you want your program to be faster you need to more effectively utilize your hard drive and network connection.  See what *their* utilization is, and ensure that they're being used effectively, and that you're only using them when you truly *need* to.

Comment: Well, only thing that is being used by a disk is reading a file.. also network's speed is fast enough so there's no way it can be network's problem. Maximum IO was like 240kb/s

Comment: @Jason Reading a file from disk is generally going to take *several orders of magnitude* longer than most CPU bound operations.  Network communications are generally going to take *several orders of magnitude* longer than disk IO.  Even if you have a fast network connection, it's almost certainly going to be the bottleneck.  Given a program like this, that isn't really doing much of anything besides file/network IO *shouldn't* have a high CPU utilization.  Doing so would be an indication of something being *wrong*.

Comment: Hmm okay, but what should I do? Or how do I analyze what is the problem?

Comment: @Jason The point is low CPU utilization **isn't a problem**.  For your program to run faster you'll need to either look at your disk/network utilization, and if one (especially the network) of their utilizations is low, look at how you can increase it.  Next look at ways of reducing or optimizing those operations, rather than the CPU bound operations.

Answer (score 0):

To use *all the hardware resources* is not the right goal for a program to have.

Instead, a better goal is to be **as fast as possible**. This is significantly different. While using more hardware resources can help, it is not always sufficient.

Sometimes, adding more resources to a problem **doesn't** help. In those cases, don't. Adding threads makes your program more complex, but not necessarily faster as you've seen.

C# already has good Asynchronous programming features with the TPL (which you are already using), so why not take advantage of that?

This will mean that the .NET framework will automatically manage the threads for you in an efficient way.

Here's what I propose:

```
foreach (var file in GetFilesToRead()) {
   var task = PerformOperation(file);
   // Keep a list of tasks, if you wish.
}

...

Task PerformOperation (string filename) {
    var file = await ReadFile(file);
    await ParseFile(file);
    DoSomething();
}
```

Note that even in CPU-bound programs, threads (and tasks) may not help you if you're using locks.
Although locks help keep programs well-behaved, they come at a significant performance cost.

**Within a lock, only one thread may be executing at a time**.

This means that the first thread is locking your `_lock` instance, and then the other threads are waiting for that lock to be released.

In your program, only **one thread is active at a time**.

To solve this, don't use locks. Instead, write programs that do not need locks at all. Copy variables instead of sharing them. Use immutable collections instead of mutable collections and so on.

My program above uses exactly zero locks and, as such, will better utilize your threads.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation, I'll try that. I'll see how it goes.

Comment: I tried your method, but it tells me that async doesn't exist in the context: http://puu.sh/6n3kn.png

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to load like x amount of files into list and monitor it from another thread and if it needs more items it will load more